# How to specify fallback priority for MediaElement player

Tags: mediaelement.js

In current MediaElement player, it use flash and silverlight fallback when HTML 5 audio feature is not available but I want to change fallback priority. What i want to do is use flash fallback in some circumstances.

I don't see any parameter about fallback priority in options. How can i do that ?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: @franzlorenzon I just ask the plugin have any option about fallback priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here: [Player fallback options](https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/253).

> In addition to setting mode you can set plugins for the priority of fallbacks:

```
MediaElementPlayer('#player', {mode: 'auto', plugins: ['silverlight', 'flash']});
```